# Akka Http + MongoDb на Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka-http

Не могу подключить официального `mongo-scala-driver` к `akka-http`. Нужно на страницу выгрузить список документов из `MongoDb` в формате `json`. Соответственно, выгружать документы хочется в асинхронном режиме - не накапливая их в коллекцию.

Этот код работает:

```
val routes = {
  pathPrefix("info") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      get {
        val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/?replicaSet=rs0")
        val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("test")
        val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("test")
        complete("info")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Выдает ответ `info`.

Я не понимаю как подключить вывод из базы в ответ сервера. Как бы я не писал, выдается ошибка компиляции. У меня есть кусок, который работает, но непонятно как его переписать:

```
collection.find().subscribe(new Observer[Document]{
  override def onNext(result: Document):Unit = ...
  override def onError(e: Throwable):Unit = ...
  override def onComplete():Unit = ...
})
```

Поиск в интернетах не дал результата: или просто работа с драйвером, или работа с akka-http с другими драйверами... Совместить не могу... Помогите...

Использую версии:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

"org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "1.2.1"
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-core" % "10.0.4"
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.4"
```

**UPDATE**: так пишет ошибку тоже

```
val observable  = collection.find()
complete(
    observable.toFuture()
)
```

**UPDATE**: в синхронном режиме получилось так

```
val feature  = Database.findAll()
val list = Await.result(feature, Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
complete(list.map(_.toJson()))
```

Как же перейти на асинхронный?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так:

```
val feature = Database.findAll()

onComplete(feature) {
  case Success(list) => complete(list.map(_.toJson()))
  case Failure(ex)   => complete((InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))
}
```

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.4/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onComplete.html